# Typescript: reference to interface in variable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, interface

While implementing the client side of a server communication I happen to meet the following problem: How can I store a reference to an interface in a variable.

I have an interface that hold all the information about a specific RESTfull backend call:

```
export interface IEndpoint {
  path: string,
  method: HTTP_METHOD,
  data: any,
  response: any
}
```

Create instance of this element (ISomeInterface and IAnotherInterface are the interfaces that I want to refer to later):

```
export const GET_TEST: IEndpoint = {
  path: 'api/test',
  method: HTTP_METHOD.GET,
  data: <ISomeInterface>{},
  response: <IAnotherInterface>{}
};
```

The goal is to use the data and response field as type references in a Promise (meta is an instance of IEndpoint):

```
new Promise<meta.response>((resolve) => {
  ...
});
```

The callback type of the Promise (meta.response) is where I am not able to extract the type/interface that I previously assigned.

Comment: `meta.response` isn't a type, it's a *value*. What context are you defining the promise in? Give a [mcve]. It's possible that this can be done with generics and/or inference, rather than specifying the promise type like that.

Comment: why not `Promise<IAnotherInterface>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values and types exist in two different domains. Types are erased at compile time so we can't assign a type to an interface field as you try to do.

What we can do is work in the type domain and keep the `data` and `response` types in the `IEndpoint` type using generic parameters, and extract them when needed.

```
export interface IEndpoint<TData, TResponse> {
    path: string,
    method: HTTP_METHOD,
    // just here because typescript doesn't handle unused generics well
    _data?: TData,
    _response?: TResponse
}

function makeRequest<T extends IEndpoint<any, any>>(endPoint: T, data: T['_data']): Promise<T['_response']> {
    return null as any// actual call
}

interface ISomeInterface { data: string }
interface IAnotherInterface { result: string }
export const GET_TEST: IEndpoint<ISomeInterface, IAnotherInterface> = {
    path: 'api/test',
    method: "GET"
};
// Takes in ISomeInterface returns Promise<IAnotherInterface> 
makeRequest(GET_TEST, { data: ""}).then(r=> r.result);
```

As @jeroen-vervaeke points out `makeRequest` could also be typed in a simpler way with the same effect:

```
function makeRequest2<TData, TResponse>(endPoint: IEndpoint<TData, TResponse>, data: TData): Promise<TResponse>{
    return null as any;
}
```

Comment: Don't you think this would be a much cleaner signature for your makeRequest method?
`function makeRequest<T extends IEndpoint<TData, TResponse>, TData, TResponse>(endPoint: T, data: TData): Promise<TResponse> {}`, this way you don't rely on the names of the fields

Comment: @JeroenVervaeke unfortunately that will not work well, the `TRsponse` will not be inferred correctly. With your version this is what gets inferred  for the call `makeRequest(GET_TEST, { data: ""})` : `makeRequest<IEndpoint<ISomeInterface, IAnotherInterface>, {
    data: string;
}, {}>`

Comment: You are correct. This is the correct signature: `function makeRequest<TData, TResponse>(endPoint: IEndpoint<TData, TResponse>, data: TData): Promise<TResponse>`

Comment: @JeroenVervaeke yes you are right that would also work :)

Answer (score 0):

You could work around your issue with a generic class and bind the method to this class :

```
export class Endpoint<T, U> {
  constructor(
    private path: string,
    private method: HTTP_METHOD,
    private data: T,
    private response: U
  ) {}

  // your new promise method there
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You refer to `meta` part in:

```
new Promise<meta.response>((resolve) => {
  ...
});
```

As it would represent a type, while it represent's a value. You can workaround it by using `typeof`:

```
new Promise<typeof (meta.response)>((resolve) => {
  ...
});
```

Or via direct reference to response type:

```
new Promise<IAnotherInterface>(resolve => {
  ...
});
```

Beside that, TS team strongly suggest to use `as` as casting operator, not `<>`:

```
export const GET_TEST: IEndpoint = {
  path: 'api/test',
  method: HTTP_METHOD.GET,
  data: {} as,ISomeInterface
  response: {} as IAnotherInterface
};
```